# Facebook Login with Trigger.io and Parse

Tags: javascript, trigger.io, parse-platform, hybrid-mobile-app

So I'm trying to implement Facebook login for my Trigger.io app but I can't figure out which method to use from the Parse SDK.

Currently I use Trigger.io's method in my login function and a Parse method that doesn't work:

```
function login() {
  forge.facebook.authorize(function (success) {
    Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn({
      authData: success
    });
  });
}
```

What I get in the success callback variable is the Facebook access token and when the access expires. They're accessed like this:

```
success.access_token
success.access_expires
```

Does anyone know the proper method and parameters I need to call to login/store a User in Parse?

Comment: Do you get any log out to suggest what's not working? My gut instinct is that you should use just the Trigger.io methods, or just the Parse methods...